# Mysql - Check table before inserting in another table

Tags: php, mysql, nested

I want to know that the admin trying to add a user to a collection actually have created that user. 
Explanation of variables:

$userid = the userid to be added to a collection

$ownerid = the admins userid

$collectionid = the collectionid the user should be added to.

> IF ($userid in (SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE 'owner' = $ownerid)) THEN INSERT INTO 'collectionusers'
>   ('collectionid', 'userid') VALUES ($collectionid, $userid);

If I execute this it looks like this

> IF (8 in (SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE owner = 1)) THEN INSERT INTO 'collectionusers'
>   ('collectionid', 'userid') VALUES (3, 8);

I have looked on:

[12.6.5.2. IF Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html)

[11.3.2. Comparison Functions and Operators - IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

I can't figure out what's wrong with this syntax.

Comment: is it essential to do all the job within single SQL statement?

Comment: Not really. It's for cleaner code.

Comment: Cleaner what? A query of non-obvious purpose is cleaner than just two separate plain actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using one query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO collectionusers(collectionid, userid)
  SELECT 3, 8 FROM users WHERE owner = 1 AND id = 8 LIMIT 1
```

Also, you can write a stored procedure.